# Approaches to C++/Javascript communication for scientific visualization

Tags: javascript, c++

I have a scientific simulation package written in C++, with poor visualization capabilities---it's hard to see what the simulation is actually doing at any one time. I would like to create a Javascript/WebGL based viewer, which would exchange data AJAX-style with the C++ simulation as it runs and visualize the results. The visualization data would comprise a few kilobytes of floating point data, and would be sent every few seconds. Communication would need to be bidirectional so that the user could specify what information is required to be visualized.

My question: what are the available libraries/technologies to be using on both sides (in the C++ application, and in the Javascript) to exchange this data?

Note: I see that similar questions to this (none of them a duplicate) have been asked and closed. I think my question is a valid one---certainly my need is genuine---and surely this is the best place to get answers. So, if there's some more productive way I should be phrasing my question, please let me know and I will do that.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @Barmar: OK, thanks for letting me know. Nonetheless I have a specific problem to which I need a solution from the community of experts. Are you saying there is no way that the stackexchange community can help me with my problem? Or is there another way for me to phrase my problem to make it on-topic?

Comment: I'm saying that this is not an appropriate question for the StackExchange community. Maybe there are other places you can find the answer to your question, I don't know. Asking for recommendations of forums would also be off-topic. SO is for programming questions that have concrete, objective answers, not for discussion, recommendations, and opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use WebSockets for the communication. The Qt library includes support for a [WebSocket server](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwebsocketserver.html) which the JavaScript client could connect to, after which bidirectional communication is possible. This also allows the exchange of binary data, which should allow you to send floating point data from the C++ side and use it at the JavaScript side as e.g. a Float32Array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This looks like a good C websockets implementation: http://libwebsockets.org/trac/libwebsockets